# PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController- How to input email & ph number from the user?

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

When i click on apple pay the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController will be popped up and here i want the user to enter email and phone number. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The below code works fine:

```
 PKContact *contact = [[PKContact alloc] init];
  contact.emailAddress = @"";
  contact.phoneNumber = [CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:@""];
  paymentRequest.billingContact = contact;
  paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = (PKAddressFieldPhone | PKAddressFieldEmail);
```